# How to prevent URLconf settings from being carried onto new project?

Tags: python, django, localhost

I recently worked on a project that had an app named 'catalog'. While I was working on it, I changed the URLconf so that the root URL could be redirected to the app.

I wrote the below code to do this:

```
# within the project's URLconf file

from django.views.generic import RedirectView
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/catalog/', permanent=True)),
]
```

I was working on the local development server, and the root URL (127.0.0.1:8000) was successfully redirected to the 'catalog' app (127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/).

However, when I created a new project, the root URL of this NEW project ALSO tried to redirect to the 'catalog' app of the previous project.
So where as I should be seeing the "it worked!" page at the root URL for the new project, I am instead redirected to the 'catalog' app's URL of the previous project, where the 404 page is displayed (obviously, because the 'catalog' app is not part of the new project).

Instead of this:
[It Worked Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4P01.jpg)

Seeing this:
[404 Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt0Lc.jpg)

It seems to me that the settings from the previous project have somehow affected the local server permanently so that the modified URLconf setting is carried on to any subsequent projects.

I could not find exactly what was causing this issue so I just ran the new project on a different port (8001) using the

```
python manage.py runserver 8001
```

command, and this seemed to fix the issue. However, I regard this only as a temporary workaround and I want to find out the root cause of the issue.

If I can't fix it, I would like to "reset" the default port (8000) so everything goes back to default settings.
Is there a way to completely "reset" either the local server or django itself so that all the settings go back to how they were released?

Comment: Are you running bot projects at the same time? If so you should run them on different ports.

Comment: The permanent redirect isn't stored by Django, it's being cached by your browser. You need to clear your browser cache to stop the redirect. Are you sure you want a permanent redirect? You can clear your browser cache at the moment, but once your site is deployed, you won't be able to clear your visitor's cache if you change your mind about the redirect.